# ajax call not returning anything to $post

Tags: jquery

Here's my code:

```
<div id="test"></div>

<form id="form-lecturer-login"> 

    <table>
        <tbody>
        <tr>
            <td>
                <label class="label">Username : </label><br>
                <input name="username" value="" type="text">
            </td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>
                <label class="label">Password : </label><br>
                <input name="password" value="" type="text">
            </td>
        </tr>
    </tbody>
    </table>
    <input value="Log In" type="submit">
</form>

<script type="text/javascript">
$('#form-lecturer-login').submit(function(){
    $.post("../php/lecturer_login.php",$(this).serialize(),
    function(data){
    $('#test').html(data[0]).show();
    }, "json");
});
</script>
```

in lecturer_login.php:

```
<?php
$stack = array();
array_push($stack,"test");
echo json_encode($stack);    
?>
```

Note: I understand I am passing data that I don't use. Just for test purposes.

'test' div does not change text to "test".

I am learning this by example and I followed jquery documentation. What am I missing?
is there any includes other than :

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="../js/jquery-1.4.2.min.js" ></script>
```

in document head that I need?

Comment: You aren't preventing the form's natural submit, therefore you never see the result.

Comment: Use Google Chrome's developer console and/or Firebug to grab the response from your AJAX call and post it here.  - Also your AJAX script is hitting `lecturer_login.php` but you reference `lecturer.php` in your code snippet, so make sure those match up as well.

Comment: the output is null from lecturer_login.php

Comment: Not that it's relevant, but why are you using such an old version of jQuery?

Comment: @KevinB how can I do that?

Comment: @Kam, try returning `false` in your `submit` event handler

Comment: Add `return false;` from the submit function.

Comment: http://api.jquery.com/event.preventDefault/

Comment: Yes returning false helped keeping the data in the test div. So basically if I hardcode $('#test').html("test").show(); that now works. but using Firebug I can see that data returned from php is null

Comment: http://learn.jquery.com/events/event-basics/

Comment: If php is returning null, the php isn't returning any json.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would do something like

```
<?php
$stack = array();
$stack['info']='test';
echo json_encode($stack);    
?>
```

And insted of $.post I prefer $.ajax

```
       $.ajax({
                url:'../php/lecturer_login.php',
                type:'POST',
                dataType:'json',
                success:function (result) {
                    $('#test').html(result.info);//since info is the key of the json maybe the same for $.post
                }
        });
```

I forgot you need

```
event.preventDefault();
```

Answer (score 0):

I think the problem is that you're not preventing the postback.

Try doing this:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
$('#form-lecturer-login').submit(function(event){
   event.preventDefault();
   ...
```

Add a parameter to your function and call the preventDefault() method.